# VB.net Error when storing lists in array

Tags: vb.net, list

I have the following code, the objective of it is to take an initial list and to take each element within the list and store it in an array of lists, with each list in the array, holding each element in its own list. For instance

```
The list 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 9, 9. Would create five lists:
List 1: 2, 2
List 2: 3, 3, 3, 3, 
List 3: 5, 5
list 4: 7
List 5: 9, 9
```

This is my current code:-

```
 Dim cnt As Integer = 0
        Dim lists(uniqueFactors.Count) As List(Of Integer)
        Dim saver As Integer = factors.Item(0)
        Console.WriteLine(saver)
        For Each i In factors
            lists(cnt).Add(i)
            If saver <> i Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
            saver = i
        Next
```

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using a [Dictonary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim storage As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
```

```
'      Number  Occurrences
'           |  |
storage.Add(2, 2)
storage.Add(3, 4)
storage.Add(5, 2)
storage.Add(7, 1)
storage.Add(9, 2)
```

You can iterate the list like this:

```
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) In storage
    Dim number As Integer = item.Key
    Dim occurrences As Integer = item.Value
Next
```

Get the number of occurrences for a given number like this:

```
Dim number As Integer = 9
Dim occurrences As Integer = storage(number) 'Return: 2
```

Change the number of occurrences:

```
storage.Item(number) = 4 'Set to 4
storage.Item(number) += 1 'Increase from 2 to 3
storage.Item(number) -= 1 'Decrease from 2 to 1
```

Create an enumerator, array and/or list of occurrences for a given number:

```
Dim iterator As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Repeat(number, occurrences).ToList()
Dim array As Integer() = Enumerable.Repeat(number, occurrences).ToArray()
Dim list As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Repeat(number, occurrences).ToList()
```

You can also write an extension method:

```
Public Module Extensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ToList(Of TKey)(source As Dictionary(Of TKey, Integer), key As TKey) As List(Of TKey)
        Return Enumerable.Repeat(key, source.Item(key)).ToList()
    End Function

End Module
```

Now you create a list by simply writing:

```
Dim occurrences As List(Of Integer) = storage.ToList(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a List of Lists like this?

```
    Dim last As Integer
    Dim first As Boolean = True
    Dim ints As List(Of Integer)
    Dim lists As New List(Of List(Of Integer))
    For Each i In factors
        If first Then
            first = False
            ints = New List(Of Integer)
            ints.Add(i)
            lists.Add(ints)
            last = i
        ElseIf i = last Then
            ints.Add(i)
        Else
            ints = New List(Of Integer)
            ints.Add(i)
            lists.Add(ints)
            last = i
        End If
    Next
```